# SQL failover with classic ASP

Tags: asp-classic, connection-string

I know that in ASP.NET there is an option in the connection string of the SQL to make a failover automatic to another server.
What is the best way to do that in classic ASP?

Comment: If it is in the connection string, just use that connection string in classic ASP as well. Is this something that requires .NET support in order to work? Can you please link to the documentation for this feature?

Comment: "Data Source=ServerA;Failover Partner=ServerB;Initial Catalog=AdventureWorks;Integrated Security=True;" you can read more here: http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1289/adonet-connection-strings-with-sql-server-database-mirroring/

Answer (score 0):

We're just working on this as well and it appears to work with SQL Server Native Client 10 and the following [connection string](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2008#p2).

```
Provider=SQLNCLI10;Data Source=myServerAddress;Failover Partner=myMirrorServerAddress;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;Integrated Security=True;
```

I'm guessing it'll also work with the ODBC version.